# Как сделать проверку сторки на наличие букв и символов JS?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать проверку строки на определенные символы и буквы?

Comment: RegEx Вам в помощь

Comment: а `indexOf()` не подходит? зачем сразу в крайности

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, если надо проверить больше одного символа - indexOf становится слишком затратным, постоянно обходить всю строку.

Comment: @Grundy Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)  и метод [тест](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Пример

Регулярное выражение ищет сначала 0 или одну открывающую скобку (?, затем три цифры \d{3}, затем 0 или одну закрывающую скобку )?, потом одно тире, слеш или точка и когда найдет это, запомнит символ([-/.]), след. три цифры \d{3}

```js
var re = /\(?\d{3}\)?([-\/\.])\d{3}\1\d{4}/;  

console.log(re.test("123-123-1234"));

console.log(re.test("123-123-124"));
```

Для проверки специального символа в Unicode используйте \uhhhh  шаблон Соответствует символам кода hhhh (четыре шестнадцатиричные цифры).

```js
    console.log(/\u20AC/.test("€"))
    
    console.log(/\u20AC/.test("%"))
```

Comment: Понятно, мне ведь по вашему вопросу не всё понять. Написал что смотреть куда копать. Удачи если помогло